# Uint8Array to ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript

So I have a ArrayBuffer which is of the file contents of a file which I read with the new HTML5 file reader as ArrayBuffer(), and I can convert the ArrayBuffer to Uint8Array by doing the following.

```
//ab = established and defined ArrayBuffer

var foobar = new Uint8Array([ab]);

//var reversed = reverseUint8Array(foobar); 

//reversed should equal ab
```

How do I reverse that last process back into ab?

Here is the kind of output I am getting after decryption: http://prntscr.com/b3zlxr

What kind of format is this, and how do I get it into blob?

Comment: The output data is a PNG file, not an "encrypted" file. Can you please show more code?

Comment: i wish to correct your code. for the same converstion, it should be `var foobar = new Uint8Array(ab);`

Answer (score 82):

I found a more simple method to get the ArrayBuffer of Uint8Array.

```
var arrayBuffer = foobar.buffer;
```

just this!
And it works for me!

Comment: Be careful this may lead to unexpected result when your data view is not equal to your buffer... See my answer

Comment: that said, your dataview is a view _of some data_, so if you're not using `new DataView(foobar.buffer)` --which is _always_ the right size-- there's a strong argument to be made that you are not using DataView correctly.

Answer (score 76):

Just using `.buffer` will not always work, because the buffer may be bigger than the data view.

See this example:

```
let data = Uint8Array.from([1,2,3,4])
var foobar = data.subarray(0,2)
var arrayBuffer = foobar.buffer; 

console.log(new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)) // will print [1,2,3,4] but we want [1,2]
```

When using `array.buffer` it's important use `byteOffset` and `byteLength` to compute the actual data

```
let data = Uint8Array.from([1,2,3,4])
var foobar = data.subarray(0,2)
var arrayBuffer = foobar.buffer.slice(foobar.byteOffset, foobar.byteLength + foobar.byteOffset); 

console.log(new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)) // OK it now prints [1,2]
```

So here is the function you need:

```
function typedArrayToBuffer(array: Uint8Array): ArrayBuffer {
    return array.buffer.slice(array.byteOffset, array.byteLength + array.byteOffset)
}
```

Comment: What is `foobar`? Please use real variable names, it helps others understand your intention.

Comment: Thank you so much. I saw the additional numbers in the beginning or the buffer and found the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

The `buffer` property of a TypedArray is an `ArrayBuffer`

```
new Uint8Array(4).buffer // ArrayBuffer(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this was the question that came every time when I searched for the answer to my problem (getting a [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) object and not an ArrayBuffer) and this is not exactly what was asked and after I reviewed all the answers here this is what I did at the end:

```
Buffer.from(file.buffer,0,file.buffer.length);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need to convert it back into an `ArrayBuffer()`, you need to add each value manually.

That means, you need to cycle through each one of them, one by one.

Probably the fastest way will be like this:

```
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(foobar.length);

foobar.map(function(value, i){buffer[i] = value});
```

Comment: Got it, but when I did try to run this code I got the following error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: foobar.map is not a function(…)

Comment: I think the Uint8Array got converted to a string after I did encryption to it, and then decrypted it again. What should we do in that case?

Comment: Ok, I think the real question is how can we convert BinaryTextData to a blob?

Comment: I still would rather do it with ArrayBuffers, I feel that they might be a little bit better.

Comment: @NickLim I'm sorry for the delay to answer. Can you please show a better example of that, in the question?

Comment: I will post the kind of output I am getting, and perhaps you can show me how to parse that data into a blob.

Comment: Ok, this is the real question. How can I convert an ArrayBuffer into a string which I can encrypt/decrypt and then reassemble that text back into the exact same ArrayBuffer?

Comment: @NickLim That is a completelly different question from what you have. Here, you are asking to convert an `UInt8Array()` into an `ArrayBuffer()`. I recommend you to write a new question, showing **clearly** the input, output and the code you tried so far.

Comment: I understand, but they are so similar and there are multiple approaches to the solution of my code because I can read the byte data in multiple ways.

Comment: Essentially, I need to be able to convert ArrayBuffer to either a string or UInt8Array() and then back to the original ArrayBuffer if that's possible.

Your method above was unable to do that for me.

Comment: Are there multiple types of ArrayBuffers? That's what it seems so perhaps your method was not applicable to my data

Comment: @NickLim There's only one "type" of `ArrayBuffer()`, which is an `ArrayBuffer()`. From the description, it is a "generic, fixed-length raw binary data buffer". How was my method unable to do that?

Comment: Sorry, for attacking your code, it's tough to isolate the problem especially when working with code that has never been written before.

Comment: Take a look at these 2: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs/blob/master/README.md#getting-started

Comment: I need to read the ArrayBuffer, convert to UInt8Array for PGP encryption, decrypt back to UInt8Array, convert that to ArrayBuffer, convert that to Blob for download.

Comment: The problem seems to be on decryption, it comes back as something that isn't a UInt8ArrayBuffer, perhaps we could try readastext on the filereader, but then how do we get that to a blob?